# Deploying the same Laravel codebase for multiple HTTP hosts on the same server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have written a backend in Laravel which I need to deploy twice on the same physical server. I need to use two different databases for these, but as they are on the same server I cannot use the built-in host detection in Laravel.

For the moment, I have "fixed" the issue by wrapping my configuration files in this code:

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] === "example.com") {
    return config array...
} else if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] === "example.net") {
    return config array...
}
```

But this breaks artisan, so no more `php artisan down|up` or `php artisan cache:clear`.

There must be a better way to achieve this, no?

Comment: Are you using Laravel 4 or 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Laravel uses your hostname, as you say - however you can also pass a closure to the `detectEnvironment` method to use more complex logic to set your environment.

Something like this, for example:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    // if statements because staging and live used the same domain,
    // and this app used wildcard subdomains. you could compress this 
    // to a switch if your logic is simpler.
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
    {
        if (ends_with($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'local.dev'))
        {
            return 'local';
        }

        if (ends_with($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'staging.server.com'))
        {
            return 'staging';
        }

        if (ends_with($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'server.com'))
        {
            return 'production';
        }

        // Make sure there is always an environment set.
        throw new RuntimeException('Could not determine the execution environment.');
    }
});
```

This doesn't deal with artisan, however - `HTTP_HOST` won't be set there. If the different sites are running under different users you can do another separate switch statement using `$_SERVER['USER']` for example. If not you could also use the path of the install as a way to differentiate.

Comment: This looks great, i believe you can pass the environment property to artisan?

Comment: Yes indeed you can, you can set that manually on the command line if you don't want to set it automatically. Also, I didn't include it here, but I also include `throw new RuntimeException('Could not determine the execution environment.');` as the last line of the closure to make sure an environment is always set.